# What's the difference between <nav> and <ul> navegations in HTML5?

Tags: html

Every now and then I find the following code structure being used for the main website navigation:

```
<nav>
   <a href="#">About Me</a>
   <a href="#">Pricing</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
 </nav>
```

And sometimes I find this one:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my question is: what's the difference between these two options since they accomplish the exact same thing. Is there a better one?

Comment: look up "semantic markup". they may act the same, but one implies it's a navigation system, while the other is just a list ACTING as a navigation system.

Comment: The nav element can help with accessibility by letting screen readers know that it isn't content but navigation links.

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/ for an important discussion on this. In particular, read the comments which give great feedback on why use of ul/li (with or without nav) is generally, though not universally, preferred.

Answer (score 3):

What you main aim needs to be is Semantics.

Here's some further reading if you're interested: http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

So basically, enclosing the UL within a NAV gives more meaning to your code and thus appreciated by good search engines.

This also makes your code more readable, which we here all love :).

Answer (score 2):

Both nav and ul elements can be used to create menu in html5,

- The nav element communicates that we're dealing with a major navigation block
- The list communicates that the links inside this navigation block form a list   of items

However you can use both nav and ul in menu creation,

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li>item 1</li>
       <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```